# How to disable href after one click

Tags: html, xslt

I wish to disable a href after clicking it once.

I have the following href:

```
<a href="BeginPayment.aspx?PayPal=true" id ="link" onclick="javascript:clickAndDisable();">
```

I have added the onclick event that gets called on click.
I have attempted to change the href to be a blank path so that it cannot be clicked a second time: This is via a Javascript function.

```
function clickAndDisable(link)
{
alert("Entered clickAndDisable function");
this.href="''";
}
```

My code is all within an xslt file.
Where am i going wrong with this?

Here is my updated code following peoples suggestions:

```
<a href="BeginPayment.aspx?PayPal=true" id ="link" onclick="javascript:clickAndDisable(this);">

<script type="text/javascript">

function clickAndDisable(link)
{
alert("Entered clickAndDisable function");
link.href="";
}
```

This disables the link from working at all, I wish for the link to work the first time it is clicked, but not work any other time it is clicked.....

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Does the alert trigger? If you're ever in doubt about the value of `this`, you can always do `console.log(this)`

Comment: Yes, the alert triggers so it is entering the function

Comment: See my answer as of why it's not working properly - and ANY answer for working solutions.

Comment: Hi Johannes, I have attempted all of your solutions but cannot seem to get any to work. The one question i do have re solution 3 is where should the click variable be declared?

Comment: I am not sure if I made myself very clear on my question. I wish for the link to be clicked once and for this to work. What i am after is any attempts to click after the first click to fail.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up disabling the href after one click using the following javascript function:

```
function check(link) {
if (link.className != "visited") {
   //alert("new");
   link.className = "visited";
   return true;    
}
//alert("old");
return false;
```

}​​

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery then you can append a class on the first click and then preventDefault after that.

```
$('a').on("click", function (e) {
    if($('a').hasClass('clicked'){
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $('a').addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

[This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samando27/tw46xb6r/) shows an example

EDIT: As pointed out by Johannes H. jQuery is not required, this can be done in pure JS as seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/samando27/tw46xb6r/2/)

Comment: This does not necessarily require JQuery. If the OP had properly used the event handler, `Even.preventDefault()` works without any jQUery - it is part of standard Javascript and not a jQUery extension

Comment: Very true! I have updated the fiddle to be pure JS https://jsfiddle.net/samando27/tw46xb6r/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Javascript like

```
   function clickAndDisable(link) {
     link.onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
     }
   }   

<a href="BeginPayment.aspx?PayPal=true" id ="link" onclick="javascript:clickAndDisable(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `.href="''"` will not set the `href` attribute to an empty value, but to the string `''`. Instead, `.href=""` does what you tried.

---

Second: `this` refers to the source element of the event within the inline `onclick` handler. However, when a function is called in the event handler, there is no special treatment for `this`, so any reference to `this` inside the function will point to the `window` object.

To solve this you can either:

1) pass the element to your function:

```
<a href="BeginPayment.aspx?PayPal=true" id ="link" onclick="javascript:clickAndDisable(this);">
```

```
function clickAndDisable(link)
{
    alert("Entered clickAndDisable function");
    link.href="";
}
```

2) use `Function.prototype.call()`

```
<a href="BeginPayment.aspx?PayPal=true" id ="link" onclick="javascript:clickAndDisable.call(this);">
```

```
function clickAndDisable()
{
    alert("Entered clickAndDisable function");
    this.href="";
}
```

3) Use Javascript to attach the event handler and dump the inline handler (in this case, `this` will be set to the `EventTarget` that triggered the handler when calling handler function):

```
<a href="BeginPayment.aspx?PayPal=true" id ="link">
```

```
function clickAndDisable()
{
    alert("Entered clickAndDisable function");
    this.href="";
}

document.getElementById('link').attachEventListener('click', clickAndDisable);
```

---

Third: encorporating @SamAnderson's answer, instead of setting an empty value for `href`, you can also set a flag on first call and evaluate if it has been set on later calls, and if so, use `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent the normal action of the hyperlink form happening:

```
<a href="BeginPayment.aspx?PayPal=true" id ="link">
```

```
var clicked = false;

function clickAndDisable(e)
{
    alert("Entered clickAndDisable function");
    if (clicked)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        clicked = true;
    }
}

document.getElementById('link').attachEventListener('click', clickAndDisable);
```

Comment: Where should I be placing the clicked variable? I have placed this in the following place but the alert "Entered click = true" only ever fires:
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicked = false;
function clickAndDisable(e)
{
    alert("Entered clickAndDisable function");
    if (clicked)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Entered PreventDefault");
    }
    else
    {
        clicked = true;
        alert("Entered clicked = true");
    }
}

Comment: My answer is a simplified attempt that onyl works if there is exactly one link that needs this treatment. The clicked variable is in global space. If you want a per-element suggesiton, I recommend @SamAnderson's answer